# Convergence rate of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am interested in finding a proof for the convergence rate of the next two sequences.

The first sequence $\{r_k\}$ is supposed to be non-negative, non-increasing and converging to $0$, which verifies the relation that there exists $N>0$, for all $k\geq N$, we have
$$\frac{3}{4}r_{k} \leq \frac{1}{4} (r_{k-1}-r_k) + a(r_k-r_{k+1})$$
where $a>0$ is some constant.

The second sequence is again a non-negative, non-increasing and convergent sequence $\{r_k\}$ (with limit $0$) such that $\exists N>0, \forall k\geq N$, we have
$$\frac{3}{4}r_{k} \leq \frac{1}{4} (r_{k-1}-r_k)^b + a(r_k-r_{k+1})^b$$
where $a>0$ and $b\in ]0,1[$ are some constants.

How to obtain the convergence rate for each sequence?
Looking forward to getting some replies. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a general way to prove both cases. Please correct me if I am wrong. The basic idea is to reduce the two terms on the right hand side to one term, which can be easily proved. As an example in the second sequence, we consider two cases by observing that the residual $r_{k}-r_{k+1}\to 0$ as $k\to \infty$.

**Case I**: if $r_{k-1}-r_{k}\sim_{k\to \infty} O(r_{k}-r_{k+1})$ (clearly including the case $r_{k-1}-r_{k}\sim_{k\to \infty} r_{k}-r_{k+1}$), then
$$\frac{1}{4} (r_{k-1}-r_k)^b + a(r_k-r_{k+1})^b = a(r_k-r_{k+1})^b + O((r_{k}-r_{k+1})^b).$$
Hence, there exist $C>0$ and $M>0$ (both large enough) such that $\forall k\geq M$, we have
$$\frac{1}{4} (r_{k-1}-r_k)^b + a(r_k-r_{k+1})^b \leq C(r_k-r_{k+1})^b.$$
Then, the problem turns to: $\exists \alpha = \frac{1}{b}>0, \beta > 0$ such that
$$r_k^{\alpha} \leq \beta (r_k - r_{k+1}), \forall k\geq M.\tag{A}$$

**Case II**: in a similar way, if $r_{k}-r_{k+1}\sim_{k\to \infty} O(r_{k-1}-r_{k})$, then
$$\frac{1}{4} (r_{k-1}-r_k)^b + a(r_k-r_{k+1})^b = \frac{1}{4}(r_{k-1}-r_{k})^b + O((r_{k-1}-r_{k})^b),$$
and
there exist $C>0$ and $M>0$ (both large enough) such that $\forall k\geq M$, we have
$$\frac{1}{4} (r_{k-1}-r_k)^b + a(r_k-r_{k+1})^b \leq C(r_{k-1}-r_{k})^b.$$
Then, we get a similar problem as: $\exists \alpha = \frac{1}{b}>0, \beta > 0$ such that
$$r_k^{\alpha} \leq \beta (r_{k-1} - r_{k}), \forall k\geq M. \tag{B}$$
In both cases (A) and (B), we can prove that $$\boxed{r_k \leq O(k^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}).}$$
Hence, sublinear convergence rate.

Similar idea can be also applied to the first sequence (despite that it is already an easy case as linear recursion). We have

**Case I**: if $r_{k-1}-r_{k}\sim_{k\to \infty} O(r_{k}-r_{k+1})$, then
$\exists \beta > 0$ such that
$$r_k \leq \beta (r_{k} - r_{k+1}), \forall k\geq M. \tag{A'}$$
**Case II**: if $r_{k}-r_{k+1}\sim_{k\to \infty} O(r_{k-1}-r_{k})$, then
$\exists \beta > 0$ such that
$$r_k \leq \beta (r_{k-1} - r_{k}), \forall k\geq M. \tag{B'}$$
In both cases, we have some $q\in ]0,1[$ such that
$$\boxed{r_k\leq O(q^k).}$$
Hence, linear convergence rate.

---

An example to show how to solve the case (A):
$$r_k^{\alpha} \leq \beta (r_k - r_{k+1}), \forall k\geq M,$$
with $\alpha>1$ and $\beta>0$.

Let $\phi(t)=t^{-\alpha}$ where $\alpha>1$. By the decreasing of $\phi(t)=t^{-\alpha}$ and $r_k\geq r_{k+1}$, we have
$$\phi(r_k)(r_k-r_{k+1}) \leq \int_{r_{k+1}}^{r_k} \phi(t)~\mathrm{d} t.$$
Then
$$\frac{1}{\beta} \leq\phi(r_k)(r_k-r_{k+1}) \leq \int_{r_{k+1}}^{r_k} \phi(t)~\mathrm{d} t = \frac{r_{k+1}^{1-\alpha} - r_{k}^{1-\alpha}}{\alpha-1}.$$
Hence,
$$r_{k+1}^{1-\alpha} - r_{k}^{1-\alpha} \geq \frac{\alpha-1}{\beta}, \forall k\geq M.$$
Summing up for $k$ from $M$ to some $T-1 (\geq M)$, we have
$$r_{T}^{1-\alpha} - r_{M}^{1-\alpha} \geq \frac{\alpha-1}{\beta} (T-M).$$
Then,
$$r_{T} \leq \left( r_{M}^{1-\alpha} + \frac{\alpha-1}{\beta} (T-M) \right)^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}} = O(T^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}).$$
Hence,
$$r_{k} \leq O(k^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}), \text{ as }k\to \infty,$$
which completes the proof.